# Lambda Calculus Reduction (applicative vs normal order)

Tags: formal-languages, lambda-calculus

I am a little confused to reduce these lambda calculus expressions. I am instructed to give applicative and normal order reductions for these expressions.

**(a) (λx. ((λy.(* 2 y)) (+ x y)))y** 
**(b) (λx. λy. (x y)) (λz. (z y))**

Here are the steps I took in my first attempt at (a): 
(λx. (* 2 (+ x y)))y 
(λx. (* 2 (+ x z)))y (substituting y with z) 
(* 2 (+ y z))

I'm unsure if I even reduced that correctly and how I would reduce in applicative order. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reduction you gave is right. However this is the applicative order.

Recall:

1. Normal order: The leftmost, outermost redex is always reduced first.
2. Applicative order: The leftmost, innermost redex is always reduced first.